# Creating csv DictReader like object

Tags: python-2.7, csv, dictionary

In my script I'm reading csv file into dictionary.

```
csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
```

The CSV structure is:

```
"Name";"type"
"Name1";"type1"
"Name2";"type2"
```

Then I loop through the `csvreader` object and use the rows as parameters for creating requests. If the response code is 404 I want to create similiar dictionary `err_obj_dict` with the similiar structure like `csv` reader, containing rows that failed with requests:

```
err_obj_dict = {'Name': [], 'type': []}

for row in csvreader:
        if row['type'] == 'virtualResource':
            objType = 'virtual'
        else:
            objType = row['type']
....
....
if resp_cd == 400:
    err_obj_dict['Name'].append(row['Name'])
    err_obj_dict['type'].append(objType)
```

Then I want do loop through `err_obj_dict` similiar way like through `csvreader` and create requests:

```
 for row in err_obj_dict:
     resp_cd = ''
     if row['type'] == 'virtualResource':
         objType = 'virtual'
     else:
         objType = row['type']
```

But the script gives me:

```
if row['type'] == 'virtualResource':
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

It seems like DictReader is creating different kind of dictionary with different structure. Would anybody help me creating ReadDict like dictionary or how to loop through `err_obj_dict` to get same result as with `csvreader`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print the result of csvreader, this would be the output.

```
for row in csvreader:
    print(row)

{'type': 'type1', 'Name': 'Name1'}
{'type': 'type2', 'Name': 'Name2'}
```

Hence, I would suggest to use an array of dictionaries instead of a dictionary with two keys `Name` and `Type`.

```
err_obj_array = []
for row in csvreader:
    if row['type'] == 'virtualResource':
        objType = 'virtual'
    else:
        objType = row['type']
....
....
if resp_cd == 400:
  err_obj_dict = []
  err_obj_dict['Name'] = row['Name']
  err_obj_dict['type'] = objType
  err_obj_array.append(err_obj_dict)
```

When you want to loop through it again, you could do

```
for row in err_obj_array:
 resp_cd = ''
 if row['type'] == 'virtualResource':
     objType = 'virtual'
 else:
     objType = row['type']
```

Comment: thnak you  @Swetha Shanmugam, how then I write err_obj_array back to  CSV file?

Comment: You can use csv [DictWriter](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-save-a-Python-Dictionary-to-CSV-file) for this.

Comment: I hope the answer helped you, if so do accept it :)

Comment: I helped I even simplified it with ommiting `err_obj_dict ` and using `err_obj_array.append(dict(row))` instead many thanks